# How can I get the current ETH gas fees in python

Tags: ether, gas, python, gas-estimate

I am trying to make a python program that gets the ETH gas prices. I am trying to avoid selenium scraping because I am using this for a discord bot. Does anyone know any good python APIs I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Will these two gas APIs help you?

- https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/gas-tracker
- https://docs.ethgasstation.info/

Answer (score 0):

This approach might also work for you:

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gas_price.html#retrieving-gas-price

Answer (score 0):

You can use `w3.eth.fee_history` with `w3.eth.get_block().baseFeePerGas`, to get estimates similar to a gas tracker.

```py
# Pass block count, target block, target reward percentiles
w3.eth.fee_history(20,'pending',[20,50,80])
# pass identifier
w3.eth.get_block('pending').baseFeePerGas
```

A simple example would be similar to one found in this walk through using javascript: https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-build-a-gas-fee-estimator-using-eip-1559

Here I have modified for python:

```py
    def format_fee_history(result, include_pending):
      block_num = result.oldestBlock
      index = 0
      blocks = []
      pending_base_fee = result.baseFeePerGas.pop()
      while block_num < result.oldestBlock + len(result.reward):
        blocks.append(
          {
            'number': block_num,
            'baseFeePerGas': result.baseFeePerGas[index],
            'gasUsedRatio': result.gasUsedRatio[index],
            'priorityFeePerGas': result.reward[index]
          }
        )
        block_num += 1
        index += 1
        if include_pending:
          blocks.append(
            {
              'number': 'pending',
              'baseFeePerGas': pending_base_fee,
              'gasUsedRatio':  None,
              'priorityFeePerGas': []
            }
          )
      return blocks
    
    def fetch_estimates():
      fee_history = w3.eth.fee_history(20,'pending',[20,50,80])
      blocks = format_fee_history(fee_history, False)
    
      hi = list(map(lambda b: b['priorityFeePerGas'][2], blocks))
      mi = list(map(lambda b: b['priorityFeePerGas'][1], blocks))
      lo = list(map(lambda b: b['priorityFeePerGas'][0], blocks))
      
      estimates = []
      estimates.append(w3.eth.get_block('pending').baseFeePerGas)
      for items in [hi, mi, lo]:
        estimates.append(round(reduce(lambda a, v: a + v, items)/len(items)))
    
      return estimates
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':  
      base, high, medium, low = fetch_estimates()
      print('max :',w3.eth.max_priority_fee + base)
      print('high:',high + base)
      print('mid :',medium + base)
      print('low :',low + base)
```